# Create a new model row with fields that are foreign keys

Tags: django, instance

I feel like the way I'm creating instances of my models must be wrong/have too many steps.

models.py:

```
class Library(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
  address=models.CharField(max_length=30)
  postcode=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Bookshelf(models.Model):
  number=models.IntegerField(default=0)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
  library=models.ForeignKey(Library, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have created a library by doing:

```
library = Library(name="town centre", address="main street", postcode = "N15"
library.save()
```

I now want to create a bookshelf for that library, but I'm not sure how to specify the library it belongs to.

```
shelfie = Bookshelf(number=5, name="fiction", library = ???)
```

I can get it to work by doing:

```
selected_library = Library.objects.get(name="town centre")
shelfie = Bookshelf(number=5, name="fiction", library = selected_library)
```

But is this correct?  When I have a view that needs to make an instance of something that has lots of foreign key/many-to-many relationships I end up with this list of assigning variables to database queries of various models so I can use them to create a single thing.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a view will use the *primary key* of the library, you can use this to assign it to `library_id`:

```
library_id = 14
shelfie = Bookshelf.objects.create(number=5, name="fiction", library_id=library_id)
```

If you create a `Library` you can also use this to create a `Bookshelf`:

```
library = Library.objects.create(name="town centre", address="main street", postcode="N15")
shelfie = Bookshelf.objects.create(number=5, name="fiction", library=library)
```

Comment: Ok, I guess my queries are just looking up these primary keys based on a string.  Is it good practice to look things up from their primary key?  I'm aware that at some point the project I'm working on will be migrated onto a different database and when I repopulate the tables the primary key might change, where the name (in this case of the library) will not.

Comment: @Chonker: but here you do not have to look up the items by primary key: you can immediately pass it when constructing the `Bookshelf` without first fetching the `Library`.

Comment: I think I understand, but if I hardcode libarary_id = 14, when my tables are created on a production server (rather than my local SQLite server) and repopulated that library_id may no-longer be 14?

Comment: @Chonker: you do not hardcode this typically: this is usually passed as a URL parameter (or POST parameter) based on the page of the library for example where you create the bookshelf.